# How to mass assign model-level permissions in the existing Django project?

Tags: python, django

I need to start using model-level permissions in my existing Django-based web service. The permission types I'd like to add are django admin's default ("add", "change", "delete") and are already there (I can see them in the admin.)

I have already many users in the database, so manual permission assignment is out of the question.

How do I auto assign these permissions for every existing user and for future users for a subset of model in my app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use groups to do so, using the get_or_create method, like the code below:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission, User
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(User)
add_permission = Permission.objects.get(content_type=content_type,codename='add_user')
change_permission = Permission.objects.get(content_type=content_type,codename='change_user')
delete_permission = Permission.objects.get(content_type=content_type,codename='delete_user')

group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='your_group')
if created: #assign permission to all users in database
    group.permissions.add(add_permission, change_permission, delete_permission)
    for user in User.objects.all():
        user.groups.add(group)
```

This way, if the group is not yet created, you create it, add all users in your database to it and add the permissions you want. Also, for every new user you want to add those permissions, you should add it to the group, so the following code should go on their creation:

```
 groupGroup.objects.get(name='your_group')
 user.groups.add(group)
```

For documentation, click [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization)

Comment: So it should be some sort of custom script or a migration?